# Why doesn't emacs store buffers internally as a tree (better random access, no line-number limitations)?

Tags: emacs-internals, line-numbers

In section 11.18 of the *GNU Emacs Manual*, it's mentioned that buffers with a large number of lines `line-number-display-limit` or with particularly long lines `line-number-display-limit-width` might experience slow performance with line number calculation and so line number calculation is disabled by default. It seems to me that using a tree-like structure you could get logarithmic-time insertion and random access if every subtree kept track of the number of elements in it. What advantage is there in doing things the way emacs does?

Comment: Do you have an implementation that clearly shows there is no advantage in doing things the way emacs now does?

Comment: The Elisp manual sections about buffers might help with this question (dunno) - node [Buffer Gap](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Gap.html), for instance. If you don't get a helpful answer here, you might ask the mailing list `emacs-devel@gnu.org`.

Comment: @EmacsUser Yi uses finger trees for its buffers. I don't know enough about emacs to experiment with ripping out the buffer data structure and replacing it with something else.

Comment: This is a fun question. One consideration is that a tree probably needs more memory allocation and certainly has worse locality of reference, than a "dumb" data structure like an array keeping a gap at point?

Comment: I made the title conform better to the content of the question, but I am not thrilled with it. My question is sort of open-ended and I am not sure what a good summary would be. Have people looked into replacing the buffer implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I doubt the buffer implementation can be blamed for every performance problem people encounter with buffers.  My specific problem with it did involve long lines that were slowing down redisplay, a known issue with a multitude of reasons behind it, including Bidi rendering, excessive movement of point crossing the problematic line and less than ideal font-lock.  I did plan on implementing a cache for line operations just to find out that such a cache does already exist.  After upgrading to Emacs 24.5, the issue was gone for me in Python REPL buffers, simply because font-lock was only applied for the input line and no more in the output.

tl;dr: There is no silver bullet.  Don't believe this is just a technical problem.  Do your own research, profile if you know how (`perf` should be ideal, `gdb` could work as well) and share your insights.

References:

- http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15555
- https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3aprkn/linumrelative_slow/csetpji
- [How do I prevent extremely long lines making Emacs slow?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-handle-files-with-extremely-long-lines#answer-603)
- [How to prevent slow-down when an inferior processes generates long lines?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/how-to-prevent-slow-down-when-an-inferior-processes-generates-long-lines/5559#5559)