# Magit hunk with long lines set default hidden

Tags: magit, performance

When I am using magit and open a a certain commit containing hunks with very long lines (a minified javascript file, css ...), emacs does not respond anymore or it becomes very slowly, luckily still responds to `C-g`.

If I manage hide this hunks in the `Magit Rev` buffer emacs behaves nicely again.

Is there a way to tell magit, if the lines for this hunk are too long, don't show this hunk?

This might be related to: [How do I prevent extremely long lines making Emacs slow?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-prevent-extremely-long-lines-making-emacs-slow)

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such feature, but there are plans to make Magit faster.